# Julia: How to join two string columns of a matrix together

Tags: arrays, string, julia

I have been combining string vectors using a comprehension, but that has felt a little clunky.

```
mymat = [collect('a':'z')  collect('A':'Z')]
[join(mymat[i,:]) for i in 1:size(mymat)[1]]
```

Comment: I'd do something like `mapslices(x->"$(x[1])$(x[2])", mymat, 2)` but I can't say it's less clunky.

Comment: I like it more. One less `size(mymat)[1]`!

Comment: If you don't care that `join` is slightly slower than `"$(x[1])$(x[2])"` (because it's more general, of course), `mapslices(join, mymat, 2)` is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches to do so.
Aware that you are joining two chars, not two strings. 
The performance differs in a wide range (1 to 79)

Aware that the type of the result differs (matrix(26x1) or vector(26))

Preparation (using Julia 0.6.0.1)

```
mymat = [collect('a':'z')  collect('A':'Z')]
using BenchmarkTools


@btime mapslices(join, mymat, 2)
   79.372 μs (425 allocations: 15.63 KiB)
   26×1 Array{String,2}

@btime mapslices(x->"$(x[1])$(x[2])", mymat, 2)
   32.144 μs (297 allocations: 10.78 KiB)
   26×1 Array{String,2}:

@btime [join(mymat[i,:]) for i in 1:size(mymat)[1]]
   45.677 μs (212 allocations: 8.95 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}

@btime [join(mymat[i,:]) for i in 1:size(mymat, 1)]
   44.494 μs (211 allocations: 8.92 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}

@btime [join(mymat[i,:]) for i in indices(mymat, 1)]
   44.806 μs (211 allocations: 8.89 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}

@btime [join($mymat[i,:]) for i in indices($mymat, 1)]
   44.806 μs (211 allocations: 8.89 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}

@btime [join($mymat[i,:]) for i in indices($mymat, 1)]
   12.411 μs (211 allocations: 8.91 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}

@btime ["$(mymat[i,1])$(mymat[i,2])" for i in 1:size(mymat)[1]]
    4.255 μs (32 allocations: 1.30 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}
```

---

```
@btime [string(mymat[i,1], mymat[i,2]) for i in 1:size(mymat)[1]]
    4.157 μs (32 allocations: 1.30 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}

@btime [string($mymat[i,1],$mymat[i,1]) for i in indices($mymat, 1)]
    1.080 μs (29 allocations: 1.20 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}

@btime string.(mymat[:,1], mymat[:,2])
   15.775 μs (56 allocations: 2.64 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}

@btime string.($mymat[:,1], $mymat[:,2])
    1.133 μs (31 allocations: 1.55 KiB)
   26-element Array{String,1}
```

Comment: Tip: you can (should) use `size(mymat, 1)` instead of `size(mymat)[1]`, and in fact perhaps `indices(mymat, 1)` for generality. Also, interpolate the variables for the `@btime` macro. `@btime [string($mymat[i,1], $mymat[i,2]) for i in indices($mymat, 1)]` is almost five times as fast with the `$`.

Comment: I was going to suggest `mymat[:, 1] .* mymat[:, 2]` or `@views mymat[:, 1] .* mymat[:, 2]` but realized that `*` isn't defined for `Char`s. Weird?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i added such cases and figured out a case which is 4 times faster than previous fastest one

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`mapslices`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/arrays/#Base.mapslices) for this:

```
julia> mapslices(join, mymat, 2)
26×1 Array{String,2}:
 "aA"
 "bB"
 "cC"
 "dD"
 "eE"
```

Comment: Oh, whoops, I see that @Michael K. Borregaard and @ Fengyang Wang beat me to it in the comments.  Post those as answers!

Comment: The return type differs from original approach